# Matching parenthesis with OneOrMore

Tags: python, pyparsing

In an application I'm working on we have a DSL that groups some characters together, they can either be grouped or not. Parenthesis determines the groups. For example, good input:

```
123
12(34)
1(234)
```

Bad input:

```
12(34
```

Essentially I want any mismatched parenthesis to not parse at all as this should be a syntax error for the purposes of what I am doing. I made this MVCE to show the issue I'm having with my pyparsing code:

```
import pyparsing as pp

def Syntax():
    lpar = pp.Literal('(').suppress()
    rpar = pp.Literal(')').suppress()
    rank = pp.Word('12345678', exact=1) #card ranking
    ranks = pp.OneOrMore(rank)
    rank_grouping = pp.Group(lpar + ranks + rpar)
    atom = ranks | rank_grouping
    return pp.OneOrMore(atom)

mvce_parser = Syntax()
try:
    mvce_parser.parseString("(76)(54")
except pp.ParseException:
    print("Exception1 was thrown!")
else:
    print("Exception1 not thrown :(")

try:
    mvce_parser.parseString("(76(54)")
except pp.ParseException:
    print("Exception2 was thrown!")
else:
    print("Exception2 not thrown :(")
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
Exception1 not thrown :(
Exception2 was thrown!
```

The issue I have here is that the first example string `(76)(54` here parses and returns `[['7','6']]` but doesn't throw the `ParseException` that I want. The second one does however fail as expected.

I'm suspecting that this is a result of `OneOrMore` suppressing the exception from the remaining part then returning what it has so far.

How can I change my code to avoid this inconsistency problem? Even though `OneOrMore` is convenient is there some other way of doing this without using `OneOrMore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to parse entire string.

To do this you either need to explicitly add `StringEnd()` to your grammar

```
return pp.OneOrMore(atom) + pp.FollowedBy(pp.StringEnd())
```

or supply the `parseString` call with the `parseAll = True` parameter

```
mvce_parser.parseString("(76)(54", parseAll=True)
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to wrap `StringEnd()` in a `FollowedBy`, you could just add it after the `OneOrMore(atom)`. But this is the old-style workaround - using `parseAll=True` is the preferred solution.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire good to know (Thanks for the awesome library too!)